# Paypal non-hosted buy now form creation

Tags: paypal

I have different products in my site to sell.
The problem is that each time for new product i have to manually create a new form using paypal and implement it in site which takes a lot time.While purchase i need two information from customers their email and phone no. .So is there any way to do this by creating a non-hosted paypal form.Can we add text-fields in non-hosted paypal forms?

For Example:(below is non-hosted paypal form how can i add two text fields to it and get them show up in customers purchase detail in paypal)

```
<div style="width:300px;background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <h2 style="text-align:center">
        Type in title here</h2>
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="paypal_form">
        <h3 style="text-align:center">
             Yummy Logo for $90</h3>
        <p align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Buy" /></p>
        <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick" /> 
        <input name="business" type="hidden" value="my_paypal_email@example.com" /> 
        <input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="logo type  x2" />
        <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="2" />
        <input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="0" /> 
        <input name="cn" type="hidden" value="Client Comments:" />
        <input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://example.com" /> 
        <input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://example.com" /> 
        <input name="rm" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
        <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
        </form>
</div>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [HTML Variables for Filling Out PayPal Checkout Pages Automatically](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0J0VU?).